# Android Spinner Selected Index

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I'm developing an android application and i want to use spinner.

I fill spinnier by String array like;

```
String ilArr[] = {"Seçiniz","İstanbul(Avrupa)","İstanbul(Asya)"};
```

and I want to add selected position number like;

When `İstanbul(Avrupa)` has been chosen from the spinner, The item index will be `34`

How can i do this.

Comment: What have you tried so far. Please show your efforts so we can correct them.

Comment: You may want to get the id of `İstanbul(Avrupa)` index is differnet from id

Comment: maintain current position value. whenever user press the item in spinner in spinner itemon click listener assign the click-able position to current position.

Comment: How i set Id of spinner